# How to run plugins on Picard as a developer

Tags: audio-player, musicbrainz, picard

I have been trying to do some open source contributions, and want to fix some issues in the plugins in Picard. however I am unable to understand how to run any plugins.

I went to the Picard-plugins repository, and used git clone to clone the repository. I want to modify the abbreviate_artistsort plugin so that when the artist has no surname, the plugin rights now throws an exception, which should be ignored. So after cloning the repo and opening it in my code editor, I ran `picard` command from the terminal. This gives me the following window as popup

[image: Picard opening window]

however I cant understand how to download, use and/or test plugins in Picard. Like suppose if i wanted to first test the abbreviate_artistsort as it is now, and then make some changes to it and test it after the changes, what should I do from here? any help or step by step guide to how to do it would be appreciated, and if possible with images and screenshots would be greatly helpful. I am using the Mac OS, so if there are any differences in the process for that kindly inform me of the same as well.

also, I came across a lot of previous posts that told how to install plugins into Picard from the options>plugins, but my options does not have a plugin choice. here’s an image of what it looks like to me:

[image: no options > plugins available]